# What are the steps for Samsung Pay integration with Cybersource on Web?

Tags: angular, payment-gateway, .net-4.8, cybersource, samsung-pay

As per the documentation on the Samsung Pay Developer site, the integration for the Samsung Pay SDK is for Android but can be done on a web framework i.e. Angular in my case.
Samsung Pay web payment integration doc: https://developer.samsung.com/internet/android/web-payments-integration-guide.html

After that is done, the payment gateway of choice is Cybersource, and the documentation shows the API to be simple as shown here: https://developer.cybersource.com/content/dam/docs/cybs/en-us/samsung-pay/developer/ctv/rest/samsungpay.pdf

The Cybersource PG (payment gateway) is implemented in .NET Framework.

The Cybersource API is returning 400 (Bad Request) for every case, I am trying for VISA since that is the primary card used.

The requet as per the Cybersource doc returns the following error response:
`"{\"id\":\"7010793680886090304953\",\"submitTimeUtc\":\"2023-11-27T10:02:48Z\",\"status\":\"INVALID_REQUEST\",\"reason\":\"MISSING_FIELD\",\"message\":\"Declined - The request is missing one or more fields\",\"details\":[{\"field\":\"paymentInformation.tokenizedCard.number\",\"reason\":\"MISSING_FIELD\"}]}"`

After I add every field Cybersource asks of the request but not mentioned in the Doc or we want to send since we can't send card data:

`"{\"clientReferenceInformation\":{\"code\":\"5038821\"},\"consumerAuthenticationInformation\":{\"token\":\"Axjr7wSTfA5W43wPsJ/ZAGRPfeXf0QE995d/RAZ4PkNA059JMvRivUO0Aak3wOVuN8D7Cf2QQXUa\"},\"errorInformation\":{\"reason\":\"INVALID_ACCOUNT\",\"message\":\"Decline - Invalid account number\"},\"id\":\"7010796011296136404953\",\"riskInformation\":{\"profile\":{\"earlyDecision\":\"ACCEPT\"}},\"status\":\"DECLINED\",\"submitTimeUtc\":\"2023-11-27T10:06:41Z\"}"`

Has anyone been able to get Samsung Pay working with Cybersource on a web project and if so how?